# angular navigate programmatically (router.navigate). Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, navigation, router

Trying inside component programmatically navigate to another route path, but have error (*ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:*).

Have next structure of app:

```
app.module.ts
main.module.ts
     milestone.ts

const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: ContentComponent
    },
      {
        path: 'milestone/:milestoneId',
        loadChildren: './content/milestone/milestone.module#MilestoneModule',
        canActivate: [MilestoneGuard]
      }],
  }
];
```

in `main.module.ts` in `imports` section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...............
    RouterModule.forChild(mainRoutes)
  ],
```

and milestoneRoute:

```
const milestoneRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MilestoneComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [{
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'qa/documents',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
      {
        path: 'qa/documents',
        component: qaDocumentsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home/documents',
        component: homeDocumentsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

milestone.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
      ..........
      RouterModule.forChild(milestoneRoutes)
      ],
```

milestone.component.html:

```
<div class="row content-wrap">
  <sidebar></sidebar>
  <main class="main-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

Navigation from template working well (we switches on `/qa/documents` ), but when trying to navigate programmatically there we have error.

Just for testing trying to navigate in ngOnInit() hook method of milestone.component.ts:

```
export class MilestoneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/documents']);
  }
```

Have the Error: *core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/documents'*

What may be the problem?

Comment: Please post how you declared your routes into your modules.

Comment: Also, feel free to make a [mcve].

Comment: Posted example of declaring of routes into modules.

Comment: If the routes are children, then you can't navigate to it with an absolute path, try setting them as root routes.

Comment: Ok, change RouterModule.forRoot(milestoneRoutes) and RouterModule.forRoot(mainRoutes), but there are next error takes place: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.

Comment: No, I meant declare them in your main routes

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly steps (maybe on the example of my app) I should take ? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Simply delete your variable `milestoneRoutes`, and put its content into `mainRoutes`.

Answer (score 3):

You should try to navigate with separate parameters in an array maybe:

```
this.router.navigate(['home', 'documents']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the method navigateByUrl, like

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/home/documents')
```

See
https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl